# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException - but not from code relating to my app

Tags: android, exception

I have an app on Google Play.  I noticed a crash report on a new Google Pixel phone.  I've reproduced that below, but on inspection it does not appear that any of the references are to code in my app, which makes it rather difficult to debug.  I'm not sure where to start on this one.

Has anyone come across this before?  I've searched elsewhere on stackoverflow but the other examples there refer back to specific lines of code in the running app.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks

Andrew

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2101)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
  at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3343)
  at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3025)
  at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3309)
  at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:356)
  at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2129)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Report timestamp

4 Jun 21:13

Application version

119

Android version

Android 7.1

Device
Pixel (sailfish)

Manufacturer
    Google
RAM (MB)
    4096
Screen size
    1920 × 1080
Screen density (dpi)
    420
Native platform
    armeabi-v7a
OpenGL ES version
    3.2
CPU make
    Qualcomm
CPU model
    MSM8996

Comment: If below answer solved your problem, please accept the answer so that anyone with the same issue would know that it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because while editing EditText Android OS is trying to show a suggestions dropdown, but your theme doesn't have the required resource file.

If possible try to update your application theme to AppCompat or add android:inputType="textFilter" to EditText fields.

I am working on the same issue since yesterday and fixed it today by using inputType property cause the clients project is very old one and requires lot of changes to update the theme.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I'll try making these changes in my app.